# 301 Redirect Confusion

Tags: redirect, tumblr, domainservices

I had a redirect from www.sixteenbynine.co.uk to a tumblr-hosted blog, but then wanted to point it towards a slightly jazzier www.sixteenbynine.ohyeahmetoo.co.uk. I did a 301 redirect in CPanel, I deleted the A records in CPanel, but I'm blowed if I can figure out why it's not redirecting.

I then tried pointing it back to tumblr, but now I just get a nasty 404.

Help me, stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is your only hope :)

Custom domains that are three or more levels deep (e.g. www.mywebsite.com or blog.mywebsite.com) need to their CNAME record to **domains.tumblr.com**

This explains why your first domain redirect worked, but the second failed.

Ref: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains